# Match a specific syntax with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to break this text and grab objects in a separated form.

```
object {
    child {

    }
}
object {

}
```

I am no regex expert, but after attempting, the best pattern I got to was something like so:

```
(.)*{(.|\n)*}/ig
```

But when applying it to the above text, it'll match it all, I can see why, but I don't know what else I could do to actually make it break the results into separate sections.

Edit:

To be more clear, in the text I provided, I'd like to have matched groups, from 'object {' to the closing '}', while including everything inside of it.

And to visualize it:
Matched group #1:

```
object {
    child {

    }
}
```

Matched group #2:

```
object {

}
```

*Just to clarify, '*object*' and '*child*' are only examples, and I want the pattern to match any names, with an option to have a child with an identical name as it's parent

Comment: Please define "it won't work". What are the expected results?

Comment: I was about to edit the question, basically it matches the entire text as it also fits the pattern.

Comment: Please edit your question to add what you expect as a result.

Comment: Is your source data always indented? Or is that just for visualization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to match this:

```
object {
    child {

    }
}
```

and this:

```
object {

}
```

as two separate matches. In that case, you just need to make your quantifier non-greedy:

```
(.)*{(.|\n)*?}
```

The `?` makes the `*` non-greedy, so instead of taking as much as possible, it'll take as little as possible.

Your original matches everything from the first `{` to the last `}` because it's greedy and that, of course, ends up grabbing everything.

The problem with the above is that it misses the last closing bracket on the first object because of nesting. You can fix this for the first level of nesting like this:

```
(.)*{({(.|\n)*?}|.|\n)*?}
```

By adding the clause `{(.|\n)*?}` as another alternative you now match the nested `child` correctly. But of course, the problem is that if you have another nested object then it'll be broken again!

Unfortunately, javascript's regex engine doesn't support recursion (some do), so you might need to take a different approach.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the awesome explanation. one thing is wrong when doing this, is that the last bracket is omitted, do you know how to overcome this issue? - well I just added a '+' after the curly bracket and it seems to work

Comment: @Don: Yeah, that is a problem that I noticed shortly after posting. The problem is that I don't believe Javascript's regex support recursive matching to any arbitrary depth.

Comment: @Don: BTW, adding the `+` only works if your objects only ever have one child. Is that the case? Or can they have multiple children (i.e. siblings).

Comment: No, it will have multiple children :(

Comment: BUT, as of now I won't need another level of children, so your solution seems to fit my needs, still testing~

Comment: Yeah it looks great, still trying to learn exactly what you've done there. the whole concept of regex confuses the hell out of me. but as your answer really works great for what I described in the question, and the great explanation, you got my vote. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
object\s*{(?:(?!\bobject\b)[\s\S])*}
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/16

```
var re = /object\s*{(?:(?!\bobject\b)[\s\S])*}/g;
var str = 'object {\n child {\n\n }\n}\nobject {\n\n}';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: This works so long as there isn't a nested object called `object`. It's not entirely clear from the OP if the top level object is always proceeded by the text `object` and whether or not the nested object might be called `object`.

Comment: @MattBurland The 'object' text is just an example, it needs to be dynamic and to fit any name, for the object and it's children.

Comment: @Don: Damn, because otherwise that was a *really* great answer.

Comment: @MattBurland It really was, I still am very impressed.